# Cache TIled Services

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I want to UnderStand what is cache Tiled Services and how can it improve performance.I am facing a performance issue in my application.I created a cache services and loaded the map without adding feature layer it performed well

```
  var opLayer1 = new esri.layers.ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer("http://10.32.9.106:6080/arcgis/rest/services/KX_Mapping/World_Countries_WMS_Cached/MapServer");
    map.addLayer(opLayer1);
```

but when i added feature layer again performance got hit , how can i imporve performance of this SO actually using cache services dint help or DId i do some mistake please help.

adding feature layer

```
featureLayer = new FeatureLayer("http://10.32.9.106:6080/arcgis/rest/services/KX_Mapping/World_Countries_VD_Look_v2/MapServer/0",{
            mode: esri.layers.FeatureLayer.MODE_SNAPSHOT,
             outFields: ["*"],
             opacity: 0.75
          });
```

Comment: You're saying you added a feature layer and then things got slow? You should be looking at improving the performance of your feature layer rather than your cached service. Take a look at the feature layer best practices doc:  https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jshelp/best_practices_feature_layers.html It would also be helpful to know the version of the API you're using and to see the code you're using to add your feature layer to your map.

Comment: JS api 3.6 and  i have added code of feature layer in the post

Answer (score 1):

A cached map service is *a hierarchical collection of tiles (images) and a file (conf.xml) which contains a description of the cache called a tiling scheme.*

The idea is that the server does not need to render an image based on the view port extent, rather it simply needs to return images already sitting on disk.  The tile cache is also beneficial when panning because you only need to download new tiles on the edge of the map instead of an image the size of the view port extent.

There are tons of resources on the web about tiling.  Also checkout [tile mill](http://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/) and [esri documentation](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisserver/9.2/dotnet/manager/publishing/static_map_svcs.htm)

Regarding the feature layer, Depending on what "mode" your feature layer is set to, you may be downloading a large amount of geometry to the client, which can be good for interactivity, but bad for performance.  If your feature layer has a large number of features, or the features are very detailed, try setting the maxAllowableOffset property which will generalize features on-the-fly if you're using arcgis server.

Comment: thanks for explanation so Cache service has nothing to do with  Feature Layer ?  So when i zoom in out so cache service will handle the  specific  tile  to be shown this is not be handeled by code.